# Error while cloning "Milo" Project from GitHub

Tags: clone, maven, classpath

i want to clone and Build Milo Project from
https://github.com/eclipse/milo

I get various errors:

- error calculating classpath for project mavenproject
- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete
- The type org.eclipse.milo.opcua...... cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

And i can not use F3 to jump into a Class / Method.

I did:

1. new project
2. Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs: deleting jre, choosing jdk
3. Window → Show View → Other… → Git → Git Repositories → Open
4. click „Clone a Git repository“
5. typing URL, next, deselect all, choose only master, next, type directory, finish
6. in "Git Respositories" right click on "Working Tree" and clicking "Import Project..."
7. creating a Working set and finish
8. (installing checkstyle)
9. open java perspective
10. switch in Package Explorer the option "Top Level Elements" to "Working Sets"
11. right click on main project -> Run As → 2 Maven build…
12. typing goals "clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse"
13. skip tests, run
14. BUILD SUCCESS

But various Error appear.

I am not experienced to maven, i am totally new, need detailed explanations with explanations of the reason WHY to do that.
I am a german user, please use simple english.

Thanks

Enomine